# How to allow application to login user with username or mobile number in Laravel 5?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am using default Eloquent authentication driver in my Laravel 5 application. I want to allow user to login with username or mobile number as well for those who have entered these two. **Is there any way to include it without creating manual authentication?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this discussion on laracasts:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/log-in-with-username-or-email-in-laravel-5

It allows the user to enter his username **or** his email. Laravel checks the field if it is an email or an username (by validating it) and depending on what it is it calls the `$auth->attempt()` function with the correct field.

The same thing should be applicable for your username or mobilenumber-problem.

Comment: Thanks Michael for sharing it. I have seen it many a times. But again it is implementing manually. I am looking if there is some way I could do it with default eloquent authentication driver instead of writing manual authentication code.

Comment: This uses the default eloquent authentication driver.
A more "native" solution is not possible.