# Laravel 5 Default Authentication Changes

Tags: laravel-5, basic-authentication

Is there a detailed article on how the default authentication works in Laravel 5?

I would like to make some changes...

1. Allowing login by username and or email.
2. Setting up an email verification.

I have found some things on Laravel 4 but does not apply to 5. Even just a list of all the files that will need to be altered would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the offical laravel 5 docs describe authentication very well: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

For the "username and/or email" part look at my answer on this question: [How to allow application to login user with username or mobile number in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881544/how-to-allow-application-to-login-user-with-username-or-mobile-number-in-laravel/29883614#29883614)

The second point isn't hard too.

1. Add an `email_validation` (or something like that) table to your database
2. Create a Controller that handles the validation requests (something like `foo.bar/validate/{email_token}`
3. On registration, send the user an email with the link to your controller
4. Validate the user, remove the token from the `email_validation` table and allow the user to login.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I found the post on the laracast site too. I'm still pretty steep on the learning curve here but it seems they are writing their own authentication controller. Correct? Not sure I am ready to try that yet and was hoping to just alter the "out of box" one. Did like the idea of separating the email verification to another table and controller rather than trying to put it in to the existing one. I will play around with that and let you know.  Thanks again!!

Comment: It's not a new authentication controller; he still uses the provided Auth Controller (`$auth->attempt()`). Thats the most "out-of-the-box" solution I know.