# Laravel 5 login by other user field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have mobile_no,username,email,password fields in my user table. I want to login through mobile no and password. How to solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow application to login user with username or mobile number in Laravel 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881544/how-to-allow-application-to-login-user-with-username-or-mobile-number-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check any field in login

```
$credentials = array(
        'mobile_number' => Request::input('mobile_number'),
        'password' => Request::input('password')
    );
if(Auth::attempt( $credentials ))
    {
      return redirect()->intended('user');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling **Auth::attempt()** manually in your controller, the solution Imtiaz provided will work like a charm.

If you're making use of **AuthenticatesUsers** or **AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers**, it's enough to just set **$username** property in your controller to a name of the field you want to use as login:

```
protected $username = 'mobile_number';
```